# SQL Server using Substring and Charindex when string varies

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I'm working on a small project to extract particular data elements from a string. An example of the string:

```
ABC:123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015
```

The part I'm trying to extract is `123-456-789-1234`. Now I have the following SQL to select that data element:

```
SELECT substring(data, charindex('ABC',data)+4,16) FROM Table X
```

The problem is that the string varies quite a bit. For example, below are how the string might also be provided:

```
ABC: 123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015
ABC:  123-456-789-1234 da1234 
ABC:  123-456-789-1234 random1234-12 1/1/2015
ABC:  123-456-789-1234,-ing  end 1/1/2015
ABC 123-456-789-1234 description end
```

Is there a better way of capturing the exact data element I want? I can't hard code a value into the substring.

Edit: Should have clarified that the string is not the same across all instances (i.e. the word description or the date is optional)

Edit: Found the answer. Needed to replace everything and just extract relevant info.

```
SELECT substring(replace(replace(replace(data,' ',''),'-',''),':',''), charindex('ABC',replace(replace(replace(data,' ',''),'-',''),':',''))+3,13)
```

Comment: I'm not good whit it, but maybe using regex

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't know if it was you're looking for:

Check it: http://rextester.com/VSRU64720

```
declare @txt table (data varchar(300));
insert into @txt values
('f df df d ABC: 123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015'),
('adf d fdf d  ABC:  123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015'),
('adf ad fdas d ABC 123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015');

with ctMsg as
(
    select substring(data, charindex('ABC',data), len(data) - charindex('ABC',data) + 1) as msg
    from @txt
)
select substring(msg, patindex('%[0-9]%', msg), 16)
from ctMsg;
```

It returns:

```
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **patindex** instead of **charindex** to find the first number appearing in a string and cut the string from this number to the place where the *description* word (with space character) begins:

```
SELECT substring(data, patindex('%[0-9]%', data), patindex('% description%', data) - patindex('%[0-9]%', data)) FROM Table X
```

---

After your data values update:

`select substring(a.data, 1, patindex('%[^0-9-]%', a.data)-1)
 from (
    SELECT substring(data, patindex('%[0-9]%', data), len(data)) as data 
    FROM Table X
    ) a`

Comment: Should have clarified that the description text also varies. Please see my updated values

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT: Updated for new data**

```
declare @YourTable table (data varchar(300));
insert into @YourTable values
('ABC: 123-456-789-1234 description end 1/1/2015'),
('ABC:  123-456-789-1234 da1234'), 
('ABC:  123-456-789-1234 random1234-12 1/1/2015'),
('ABC:  123-456-789-1234,-ing  end 1/1/2015'),
('ABC 123-456-789-1234 description end') 

Select stuff(left(data,patindex('%-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',data)+4),1,patindex('%[0-9]%',data)-1,'')
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
123-456-789-1234
```